# Dynamically set the column editor for each row in tabulator

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I have a customer that has metadata in each row describing what type of data is in the column.  Is it possible to set editor for a column differently for each row?

```js
var tab = new Tabulator('#tabId', {
    data: data,
    layout: 'fitColumns',
    columns: [
        {
            title: 'Name',
            field: 'LocationName',
        },
        {
            title: 'Field',
            field: 'Field',
            editor: (cell, onRendered, success, cancel, editorParams) => {
                // is it possible to just return one of the built in editors here, if so how?
                // I only need text, date, checkbox built-in types, but need to determine which 
                // one dynamically based on data in the row.
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible to do with standard editors, these must be defined by column, but you could could create a [Custom Editor](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.5/edit#edit-custom) that could return one of a number of editors, and chooses which one to return based on the row data.

You can get the source for the inbuilt editors from the `src\js\modules\edit.js` file in the repo